# How to use a JavaScript array to retrieve a JSON object's values all at once via a for loop

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, keyvaluepair

Is there a way, in JavaScript, to use an array to loop through and retrieve a JSON object's values in a for loop in one go?

I have one array dedicated to the keys in my JSON object:

```
var PersonArrayKeys = ["LastName", "FirstName", "MiddleName"];
```

And my JSON object:.

```
var javaObj = '{ "LastName": "LN", "FirstName": "FN", "MiddleName": "MN"}'
var obj = JSON.parse(javaObj);
```

I can get the value if I just refer to the object's key like so,

```
console.log(obj.LastName);
```

But if possible I'd like to get all of them in one go. This was the only thing I could think of, but it gives an "Unexpected token : in JSON."

```
var objText;
for (j = 0; j < PersonArrayKeys.length; j++) {
     console.log(PersonArrayKeys[j] + " key");
     objText += obj.PersonArrayKeys[j];
}
console.log(objText);
```

Comment: You want to get all of the values in one go?

Comment: @MattOestreich Yes, if it's possible. I'm sorry, I thought I'd explained that. I will adjust the wordage in my question.

Comment: Whever you write  question on SO, read it 2-3 times and make it simple. It will save some time for person trying to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use this oneliner instead of the loops - it enumerates all the value and merge them into one string.

```
var objText = Object.values(obj).join(' ')
console.log(objText)
```

Comment: Marking this as answer because it's short, sweet, and simple. That and I'd completely forgotten about the Object Constructor!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but you can use a for...in loop to do what I think you are asking. for...in loops are an easy way to loop over an object. See below for example where I log out the key and the value.

```js
var javaObj = '{ "LastName": "LN", "FirstName": "FN", "MiddleName": "MN"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(javaObj);

var text = '';
for(var item in obj) {
  console.log(item + " " + obj[item])
  text += obj[item];
}
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Ah, I see! I had not thought of that! I was stuck on for-loops because the rest of the code used it. This too, answers the question, but unfortunately I cannot have more than one marked answer :(

Answer (score 1):

You can code `objText += [obj.PersonArrayKeys[j]];`

```js
var PersonArrayKeys = ["LastName", "FirstName", "MiddleName"];
var javaObj = '{ "LastName": "LN", "FirstName": "FN", "MiddleName": "MN"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(javaObj);
console.log(obj);
var objText='';
for (j = 0; j < PersonArrayKeys.length; j++) {
     objText += obj[PersonArrayKeys[j]];
}
console.log(objText)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried that already and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Nondeplume Is that because you are missing an ```'``` at the end of your ```javaObj``` What is the error?

Comment: @Spangle Thank you for catching that, but no that was because I'd omitted some data when doing copy-n-pasta. Adjusted my question to fix that.

Comment: @RyanNghiem Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve! Thank you!! Unfortunately, I can only mark one answer :(

Answer (score 0):

You can deconstruct the object. Since you know the keys, I suggest the following...

```
var javaObj = '{ "LastName": "LN", "FirstName": "FN", "MiddleName": "MN"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(javaObj);
let {LastName, FirstName, MiddleName} = obj;
console.log(LastName, FirstName, MiddleName);// LN, FN, MN
```